# What's the correct syntax for Execute SQL in Processing QGIS 2.6?

Tags: qgis, sql, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

I made a small model with Processing in QGIS 2.6.

The final layer should be the result of a SQL query. Now, in the `Execute SQL` dialog window I can add the query:

```
select name, max(ele) as ele, geom
from layer_id
group by id
```

but I haven't understood which name have I to specify in the query (`layer_id` in the example).

Answer (score -1):

Parameters
Database [string]
Name of the database, not the connection name. By default you don’t have to fill in the name, the current database connection will be chosen.

Default: (not set)

SQL query [string]
Defines the SQL query, for example ‘create schema test;’.

Default: (not set)